# After Sudden restart of laptop all the code in controller is invisible

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller

I am working on asp.net mvc application.
When i was working on application, laptop got restart.
After restart when i run my application, my specific controller (on which i was working on restart time) is not opening. When i double click on it in solution explorer it open a notepad blank file with very short(according to my code) scroll bar.

When i double click in solution explorer:
[image: When i double click in solution explorer]

When i open Controllers folder in windows explorer, it show full file size as it originally was having.

[image: in windows explorer]

Please help me, this is my 3 months hard work.

I am new developer and first time asking a question.
If there is something wrong in asking question, please guide me, Thanks

Comment: did you try copying that 1 file to an other location and then opening it individually?

Comment: It looks like the content of the file has been lost and its pure whitespace / null characters now. Unless you had a backup in source control, a copy somewhere, or otherwise, the situation is pretty grim.

Comment: Let this be a lesson: **always** use source code control. I recommend Git.

Comment: I had similar issue last week.  I edited a file in notepad and the file got saved as xxxxx.cs.txt.  So I was using the wrong file.  The link you provided looks like the file size is not zero yet notepad is showing an empty file.

Comment: When i try to open in MS Word, it look like  http://prntscr.com/fkll57

Comment: And if it just lost data then why not it is opening in vs? When i click on that controller name in solution explorer it does not open cs file, it open notepad file. . . .

Comment: Your file is likely corrupted. You can view the file in a hex editor and see if you can recover the data..

Comment: I open it in hex editor, this is the result http://prntscr.com/fkm3yj . Is there any hope?

Comment: If everything is the same character, that means the file no longer contains your data.

Comment: OMG. . . . it's very painful for me 

Comment: Well that's certainly frustrating. But you will remember this as the last time you ever lost work. Because now you've felt the effects and know to use source code control and take backups, right?